# why does this program display the output infinitely instead of displaying once and asking for an input

Tags: python-3.x

1.The loop walks fine but i want it to display the result once.

```
import math
mark =int(input("Enter mark..."))
while (0<=mark<=100):
# grading marks
    if (75<=mark<=100):
        print ("A")
    elif (60<=mark<=74):
        print ("B")
    elif (50<=mark<=59):
        print ("C")
    else:
        print ("you bitch") enter code here
mark =int(input("Enter mark..."))
```

Comment: Because there's no break in your `while` loop.

Comment: Why are you importing the `math` library when you don't use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to continuously ask for marks and print the output, all you need to do is ask for the input *inside* the loop, like so:

```
import math
mark =int(input("Enter mark..."))
while (0<=mark<=100):
# grading marks
    if (75<=mark<=100):
        print ("A")
    elif (60<=mark<=74):
        print ("B")
    elif (50<=mark<=59):
        print ("C")
    else:
        print ("F")
    mark =int(input("Enter mark...")) #indented this line.
```

Please note that I changed the wording in the last `else` block because of language concerns.

Hope that helps you out.